# Error code: BadArgument Error message while sampling data from Azure Stream Analytics Job

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I tried to take sample data from a running Azure Stream Analytics Job. The job is running successfully and the output is writing into cosmos DB successfully.

But when I tried to take sample data from the streaming input, Sampling is failed and I am getting below error.

> Error code: BadArgument
>   Error message: There was an error while reading sample input. Please check if the input source is configured correctly and data is in correct format.
>   [image]

If it is because of data format, the job should have also failed?

I tried taking sample from another SA job which is using same event Hub but only the difference is, it is using different consumer group, for that I am able to fetch the sample data.

What could be the reason for this failure since the job is working successfully with that input? Is there anything that have to be corrected in consumer group?

Is there any workaround to get sample data from eventhub with some filtering?

Comment: hi,antony. I'm confused about your sample input? you mean upload sample data in the ASA portal? What's the sample data? Pls post it here so that i could try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Input for the ASA job is eventHub.  For taking sample from eventHub which is added as input to ASA job, I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the same Event Hub consumer group is being used by different consumers. Try creating a new consumer group for your event hub and configuring your job's input to use this new consumer group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshoot-input#job-exceeds-maximum-event-hub-receivers

Comment: The consumer created is only used in this SA job.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working and I am able to take sample from SA job input. Didn't do anything from my end, don't know what exactly was the reason, since it was not working for last one week.